# Synchronous and Asynchronous exceptions in Java

Tags: java

While reading [jvm specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf) I came across exception (2.10 Exceptions)

> Most exceptions occur synchronously as a result of an action by the
>   thread in which they occur. An asynchronous exception, by contrast,
>   can potentially occur at any point in the execution of a program ...

What are the differences between the two types ?

Keeping reading, the specification gives and example of an asynchronous exception

> An asynchronous exception occurred because: – The stop method of class
>   Thread or ThreadGroup was invoked, or – An internal error occurred in
>   the Java Virtual Machine implementation.

But what makes stop method of a class thread special in this regard ?

**Can you explain the differences between the two and give some examples of them, other than the given ones ?**

Comment: The difference is mention in the question .. "_Most exceptions occur synchronously as a result of an action by the thread in which they occur._" this let me think an aync exception is the result of an action from another thread ;)

Answer (score 1):

The stop method can be called from another thread which could leave the data altered by the thread stopped in an inconsistent state.

For this reason Thread.stop() is being removed. I suggest you not use it.

> Can you explain the differences between the two and give some examples of them, other than the given ones

The difference is that an asynchronous exception is triggered by another thread at any point in the code.

They should not happen under normal operation.

A specific implementation of the JVM could have other errors but there is not exhaustive list.
There isn't much you can do about except shutdown gracefully.

Comment: Is it the only example of asynchronous exception ? (I am not familiar with those) Which seems to be more the subject here.

Comment: It's not a situation you can really handle and it should not happen under normal operation.

Comment: _it should not happen under normal operation_, isn't this the definition of an exception ;) So you imply that those kind of exception (not simply one from `Thread.stop`) should be simply ignored ? (Seen your edit, that's answer my last comment)

Comment: @AxelH you should shutdown gracefully. While Exception are exceptional, they can happen quite often in a normal program e.g. when a socket disconnects.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example showing the two types of exception. Consider the following code snippets, which show the two kinds of exception being raised, and handled:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        syncException();
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        System.out.println("-1-");
        re.printStackTrace();
    }

    CompletableFuture<Void> f = null;
    try {
        f = asyncException();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        System.out.println("-2-" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        f.get();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("-3-");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

A synchronous exception

```
private static void syncException() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Sync exception @" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

And an asynchronous exception - raised in a different thread from the calling code:

```
private static CompletableFuture<Void> asyncException() {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("Async exception @" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
}
```

Now, when that code is executed, the following stack traces are produced:

The synchronous exception's stack trace:

```
-1-
java.lang.RuntimeException: Sync exception @main
    at stackoverflow.Main.syncException(Main.java:34)
    at stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Note that `-2-` was not printed, because the exception was asynchronous. See the third `catch` block's stack trace for how asynchronous exceptions are handled. Note that the thread in which the exception was raised is different from the one printing the stack trace:

```
-3-
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Async exception @pool-1-thread-1
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Async exception @pool-1-thread-1
    at stackoverflow.Main.lambda$0(Main.java:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

> An asynchronous exception, by contrast, can potentially occur at any point in the execution of a program ...

Just a comment on this: you'll notice that the code in thread `pool-1-thread-1` could raise the exception any time of the `main` thread's execution. This is probably relative among threads. But in this example, the `main` thread being the main programe execution, we can say that the `"Async exception @pool-1-thread-1"` exception occurred asynchronously.